# Why is spark unable to read a large JSON text file despite of sufficient memory for both execution and cache?

Tags: json, apache-spark, garbage-collection, bigdata, apache-spark-mllib

I have configured a standalone cluster (a node of 32gb & 32 cores) with 2 workers of 16 cores & 10gb memory each. The size of the JSON file is only 6gb. I have tried tweaking different configurations, including increasing young generation memory. Is there anything else I am missing?

PS: This doesn't work even in spark-shell.

Configurations inside env file.

- SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=8g
- SPARK_WORKER_CORES=16
- SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=2
- SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=10g

I have tried following config params while submitting job:

```
./spark-submit --driver-memory 4g \
               --supervise --verbose \
               --conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer \ 
               --conf spark.memory.fraction=0.2 \
               --conf spark.memory.storageFraction=0.5 \
               --conf spark.network.timeout=10000000 \
               --conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=10000000
```

---

```scala
val dataFrame = spark.read.option("multiline", "true")
                          .schema(schema)
                          .json(jsonFilePath)
                          .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2)

dataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("node")

val df = spark.sqlContext.sql("select col1, col2.x, col3 from node")
                         .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2)

val newrdd = df.repartition(64)
               .rdd.mapPartitions(partition => {
                val newPartition = partition.map(x => {
                    //somefunction()
                }).toList
                newPartition.iterator
            }).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2)
```

Error:

```
     Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 131.123.39.101, executor 0): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please give details!

Comment: " unable to read large json " is generic/abstract sentence. when you read the json how many partitions have you repartitioned to achive parllelism ? if so how much data is going to each worker. in general case 2 * 16 * (2-3) = 64  - 96 partitions would be good.  Ideally what I mean is make sure that data is distibuted uniformly across... also mention spark submit / version /code if you ask a question.. it should be concrete

Comment: If your json is compressed, it will explode in the mappers, since the split size computation doesn't account for the compression ratio.

Comment: First, you may give more detail for example your code , JSON schema, and exception or error you occur. Does you spark program fail after read JSON file ?

Comment: @howie my program fails while reading the JSON file. However, it passes for a small size file. I have added code and exception error. Thanks,

Comment: @DaRkMaN No it is not compressed. It's a regular JSONObject with 2 levels nested.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram I have tried partitioning 32, but it shows the same error. I am using Spark 2.4.3.

Comment: @U.Windl I have updated details. Thanks

Comment: try to increase driver memory~

Comment: @howie I have passed 4g as a driver memory while submitting spark job. It didn't work.

Comment: Because toList will collect data back to driver, you may also try this https://databricks.com/blog/2015/05/28/tuning-java-garbage-collection-for-spark-applications.html